# 1/2 solved - Error removing old /etc/fstab entry to mount HDD

Tags: mount, fstab, external-hdd, unknown-device

I could use a pointer on fixing the fstab problem to restore earlier working order. I dont have owner in mnt directory and its all snafu. Thank you very much.

I tried changing the mount point of a external HDD. Failed. This is the end.

```
mount /dev/sdc

mount: /dev/sdc: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

When mounting it with Disks this appears:

**Error mounting filesystem**
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdc1: unknown filesystem type 'nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show' (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Editing mount options in Disks this appears:

**Error removing old /etc/fstab entry**
Didn't find entry to remove (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Thank you again.

Comment: Could you add the command you used ?

Answer (score 1):

This jimmy rigged it.

Create a directory that you will use as the mountpoint for your drive:

```
mkdir /mnt/mydrive
```

Mount your drive with this command:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mydrive
```