# I am facing problem while trying to mount of my drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I am facing this issue while trying to mount on my drive:

[image: Screenshot]

There are two drives on my PC, one is for OS only (SSD) and another one 1TB (HDD). The problem with 1TB hard drive, there are 3 drives, two are fine. But facing trouble with 1 drive which has lots of data. I am unable to mount it. What should I do?
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Comment: Based on the way you have worded this question I count 5 drives maybe 6. Please edit the question and clarify. Maybe the one large drive has 3 partitions? That would not be 3 drives.

Comment: Feed us some more information. What make model and age is the drive? SSD or HDD spinner? 5400 or 7200 rpm. 3.5" or 2.5"? Hoping its NVMe, m.2,SATA and not IDE. Internal or eSATA or USB? What file system? ext4, ntfs, exfat, others? Show output for 1TB drive for these commands (with sudo) `lsblk` `blkid` `fdisk -l` `parted -l` Try running `fsck /dev/sxx` That tries to fix disk errors
Also check with `smartctl -l /dev/sxx` of course replace sxx with your drive `smartctl` has short and long test you can run. Usually failures here are show stoppers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1/2 solved - Error removing old /etc/fstab entry to mount HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311226/1-2-solved-error-removing-old-etc-fstab-entry-to-mount-hdd)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, but if urgent, maybe you try to mount in terminal:

for example like:

sudo mkdir /mnt/ntfsdrive

sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sda4 /mnt/ntfsdrive